# Referencing dlls built with older .Net versions

Tags: .net, dll, reference

In a project using .Net4 - should there be any issues referencing dlls built for older versions of .Net? We're talking 3rd Party dlls here.

I'm asking this as a general question. Specifically I have a [problem referencing FluentNHibernate.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697795/using-fluentnhibernate-with-net4) - built with .Net3.5. It worked justed fine before I updated my project from .Net3.5 to .Net4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No in general you can have a .Net 4.0 project reference any dlls even if they were compiled against older versions of .Net.

Looking at your linked question: It could be that libraries that inject/modify IL are affected by versioning problems because the injections are not under the control of the .Net runtime system.

Comment: Thx - that was what I assumed. Thanks for input on the other question too. Will look into it.

Comment: I also added an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688993/problem-with-sqlite-related-nunit-tests-after-upgrade-to-vs2010-and-re5 regarding the changed default build targets in VS2010 that MAY bite you.